# What is the correct way to store all the dynamic Json response strings to a list in restassured java?

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, rest-assured

```
public void getresponseString() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getInfoResp.jsonPath().getInt("Map.List.size()"); i++) {
        ArrayList<String> country = getInfoResp.jsonPath().get("Map.List[" + i + "]" + ".country");
    }
}
```

JsonResponse:

```
{
"plan": {
    "program": "gtr",
    "syter": "yes"
},

    "Map": {
        "List": [
            {
                "id": "tyt6577",
                "proxy": "ENABLED",
                "type": "BENEFIT",
                "country": "us",
                "triag": null
            },
            {
                "id": "yyaqtf6327",
                "proxy": "ENABLED",
                "type": "BENEFIT",
                "country": "aus",
                "triag": null
            },
            {
                "id": "676hwjsgvhgv",
                "proxy": "ENABLED",
                "type": "BENEFIT",
                "country": "rus",
                "triag": null
            },
           {
                "id": "676hsdhgv",
                "proxy": "ENABLED",
                "type": "BENEFIT",
                "country": "spa",
                "triag": null
            },
           {
                "id": "623ujhhgv",
                "proxy": "ENABLED",
                "type": "BENEFIT",
                "country": "cha",
                "triag": null
            }
           
        ]
    }
```

}

In the above method, I try to store all the strings of Jsonresponse in List but I got this error finally "**java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList**"
What is the correct way to store all the dynamic strings to list?

Comment: Need response to see what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 ok, I have attached the Json Response. Please check.

Comment: What exactly data do you want to extract? Is it `country`?

Comment: yes it's country

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split the `json` and store the response in the `ArrayList<String>`

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.stream(response.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

You can split it either by comma or any other String/Char

Comment: Its not working

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to extract `country` here is:

```
ArrayList<String> country = getInfoResp.jsonPath().get("Map.List.country");
//[us, aus, rus, spa, cha]
```